# jquery ajax returning sending page html

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc

My ajax code

```
$.ajax(
    url : '/ABC/xyz.htm',
        type : 'POST',
    success : function(response) {
    alert("success :" + response);    
            },
            error : function(res) {

                alert("error");
            },

        });
```

My controller code is

```
@ RequestMapping ( value = "/xyz" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public @ ResponseBody String getBranchList ( ) {    
    return "success";

}
```

But its returning full html page.

Am using spring 3.1.2

Please help me to solve this

Comment: What exactly is your expected return?

Comment: I returned "success" string but it returning full html page

Comment: Okay you can use jquery to add your response to a div in your jsp.

Comment: Actually it should return the success string , P.S url in jsp is /xyz.htm, but in your controller it is /xyz,

Comment: can you add success:function(data) instead of response, and see the result.

Comment: ya i tried that too but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you check you have below maven dependency, if it is maven project,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>           
</dependency>
```

the above data Mapper package is a high-performance data binding package built on Jackson JSON processor.
or else add the jar in your classpath.

EDIT-
also see this post , for need of this jar.. the response you get back is html, but by adding the below jar, will convert you html to json object, hence you can access the attribute set in your controller
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Sorry its not a maven project

Comment: ok .. you can download the jar.. and add to your classpath. this jar need to be there for your response for data binding